# Failed building OpenCL Apple Silicone (buildComputeProgram: cl2Metal failed)

Tags: c++, opencl, apple-m1

I wrote simple C++ program with the use of OpenCL and it does not build (Apple M1 GPU).

*I have omitted some declarations*

main.cpp

```
// Load the kernel source code into the array source_str
    FILE *fp;
    char *source_str;
    size_t source_size;

    fp = fopen("vector_add_kernel.cl", "r");

    source_str = (char *) malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1,
                         &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
// Create an OpenCL context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret); // Create a command queue
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);
// Create memory buffers on the device for each vector
    cl_mem a_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem b_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem c_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
// Copy the lists A and B to their respective memory buffers
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, a_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), A, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, b_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), B, 0, NULL, NULL);
// Create a program from the kernel source
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) &source_str,
                                                   (const size_t *) &source_size, &ret);
// Build the program
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);
// Create the OpenCL kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "vector_add", &ret);
```

vector_add_kernel.cl

```
_kernel void vector_add(__global const int *A, __global const int *B, __global int *C) {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
```

Got the `UNSUPPORTED (log once): buildComputeProgram: cl2Metal failed`.

The only g++ flag that I applied is `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-framework OpenCL")`.
Both GNU GCC nor Clang meet the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a typo, try `__kernel` instead of `_kernel`.